# Get the last row values filled in current sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to fetch the last row values of the form response tab sheet to the current sheet and then Transposed and displayed columnwise excluding the first timestamp column

I tried but this get unexpected results

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("'Form Resposes1'!" & COUNT('Form Resposes1'!A:A)+1 & ":" & COUNT('Form Resposes1'!A:A)+1))
```

The response tab sheet looks like:

[image]

The expected result from the formula is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if your sheet is named "Form Responses 1":

> =TRANSPOSE(SORTN('Form Responses 1'!B2:H,1,0,'Form Responses 1'!A2:A,0))

**References:**

- [SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)